Can someone help me understand what are FX Grid changes
In stress testing, some drivers of day on day moves are driven by fx grid changes in e.g. USD downside driven by vanilla options positioning in EURUSD (EUR +x%, +y%,+z% shock) from expiry of long strikes and addition of short strikes.
can someone explain, what exactly does this statement mean??

Where did you see this statement please?

@DimitriVulis this is a general comment I see a lot in Market Risk - is this widely understood ? I am curious to know

I, for one, get the general gist, but have difficulty understanding fully without more context. It sounds like 1) someone's engaged in FX grid trading (OK definition: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/grid-trading.asp ), 2) is attributing the changes in the valuation of their book under market risk stress test scenarios to the changes in their grid, i.e. in their FX bets 3) possibly on purpose, not being clear to me how they changed their grid from this sentence - maybe more details in other sentences.
